# Difference between OpenMP #pragma omp for v/s #pragma omp parallel for?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

What is the difference between :

```
 #pragma omp for
  {for_loop}
```

and

```
 #pragma omp parallel for
  {for_loop}
```

Comment: its not the same.... omp for and not simple omp

Comment: ok, my bad. It's not exactly the same, but it provides enough info to answer your question. I added an answer to your specific question.

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma omp parallel`

This spawns a group of threads.

`#pragma omp for`

This divides the loop iterations between the threads.

Basically,

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (...)
{}
```

is the same as

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (...)
{}
```